# How To Play Multiple Sounds in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I´m developing an Augmented Reality piano with Vuforia and Unity 4.6. The app will be a game where the mobile phone will say a note, for example :"C" and the user will have 5 seconds to play the note in a paper piano with virtual buttons.

The problem I´m having is that I´m not getting the sounds of the piano keys when I press a button. I do enter the desired case in the switch statement, but no sound is played.Neither the play() methods on the Update function or the OnButtonPressed() are playing. However on the method generarNota(). I always listen the sound of the phone saying the note.

This is my code:

```
public class ButtonControl : MonoBehaviour,IVirtualButtonEventHandler {
    public AudioSource c;
    public AudioSource cSharp;
    public AudioSource d;
    public AudioSource dSharp;
    public AudioSource e;
    public AudioSource f;
    public AudioSource fSharp;
    public AudioSource g;
    public AudioSource gSharp;
    public AudioSource a;
    public AudioSource aSharp;
    public AudioSource b;
    public AudioSource correctSound;
    public AudioSource incorrectSound;
    public AudioClip cv;
    public AudioClip cSharpv;
    public AudioClip dv;
    public AudioClip dSharpv;
    public AudioClip ev;
    public AudioClip fv;
    public AudioClip fSharpv;
    public AudioClip gv;
    public AudioClip gSharpv;
    public AudioClip av;
    public AudioClip aSharpv;
    public AudioClip bv;
    public AudioSource c2;
    public bool gameOn;
    string currentNote; //Nota genereada por el sistema
    string inputNote; //Nota presionada por el usuario
    public float waitTime; //Tiempo de espera entre notas
    public float resetWait; // Para reiniciar el tiempo de espera
    public int totalNotes;
    public int correctNotes;
    public int incorrectNotes;
    bool firstNote;
    bool beingHandled;
    public bool blackNotes;
    bool notePressed;
    //Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        c.PlayOneShot(c.clip);
        blackNotes = false;
        this.notePressed = false;
        beingHandled = false;
        currentNote="NONE";
        waitTime = 0;
        firstNote = true;
        VirtualButtonBehaviour[] vbs = GetComponentsInChildren<VirtualButtonBehaviour>();
        for (int i = 0; i < vbs.Length; ++i) {
            // Register with the virtual buttons TrackableBehaviour
            vbs[i].RegisterEventHandler(this);
        }

    }
    void generarNota(){
        if (blackNotes) {
                        int num = Random.Range (1, 13);
                        //StartCoroutine ("waitTimeDelay");
                        switch (num) {
                        case 1:
                                Debug.Log ("Se genero C");
                                int a = 0;
                                currentNote = "C";
                                audio.clip = this.cv;
                                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
    //this.aSource.PlayOneShot(this.cv);
                                break;
                        case 2:
                                Debug.Log ("Se genero C#");
                                currentNote = "C#";
                                audio.clip = this.cSharpv;
                                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
                                break;
                        case 3:
                                Debug.Log ("Se genero D");
                                currentNote = "D";
                                audio.clip = this.dv;
                                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
                                break;
                        case 4:
                                Debug.Log ("Se genero D#");
                                currentNote = "D#";
                                audio.clip = this.dSharpv;
                                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
                                break;
                        case 5:
                                Debug.Log ("Se genero E");
                                currentNote = "E";
                                audio.clip = this.ev;
                                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
                                break;
                        case 6:
                                Debug.Log ("Se genero F");
                                currentNote = "F";
                                audio.clip = this.fv;
                                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
                                break;
                        case 7:
                                Debug.Log ("Se genero F#");
                                currentNote = "F#";
                                audio.clip = this.fSharpv;
                                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
                                break;
                        case 8:
                                Debug.Log ("Se genero G");
                                currentNote = "G";
                                audio.clip = this.gv;
                                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
                                break;
                        case 9:
                                Debug.Log ("Se genero G#");
                                currentNote = "G#";
                                audio.clip = this.gSharpv;
                                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
                                break;
                        case 10:
                                Debug.Log ("Se genero A");
                                currentNote = "A";
                                audio.clip = this.av;
                                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
                                break;
                        case 11:
                                Debug.Log ("Se genero A#");
                                currentNote = "A#";
                                audio.clip = this.aSharpv;
                                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
                                break;
                        case 12:
                                Debug.Log ("Se genero B");
                                currentNote = "B";
                                audio.clip = this.bv;
                                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
                                break;
                        }
                        this.totalNotes++;
                } 
        else {
            int num = Random.Range (1, 8);
            //StartCoroutine ("waitTimeDelay");
            switch (num) {
            case 1:
                Debug.Log ("Se genero C");
                int a = 0;
                currentNote = "C";
                audio.clip = this.cv;
                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
                //this.aSource.PlayOneShot(this.cv);
                break;

            case 2:
                Debug.Log ("Se genero D");
                currentNote = "D";
                audio.clip = this.dv;
                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
                break;

            case 3:
                Debug.Log ("Se genero E");
                currentNote = "E";
                audio.clip = this.ev;
                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
                break;
            case 4:
                Debug.Log ("Se genero F");
                currentNote = "F";
                audio.clip = this.fv;
                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
                break;

            case 5:
                Debug.Log ("Se genero G");
                currentNote = "G";
                audio.clip = this.gv;
                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
                break;

            case 6:
                Debug.Log ("Se genero A");
                currentNote = "A";
                audio.clip = this.av;
                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
                break;

            case 7:
                Debug.Log ("Se genero B");
                currentNote = "B";
                audio.clip = this.bv;
                audio.PlayDelayed (0.5f);
                break;
            }
            this.totalNotes++;



        }

    }
    void waitTimeDelay(){


    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (this.gameOn) {
            if(this.waitTime>0){
                this.waitTime-= Time.deltaTime; 
                //Verificamos el boton. Si esta presionado el correcto sumamos a las notas correctas
                if(inputNote==this.currentNote){
                    //audio.clip = this.correctSound;
                    //audio.Play();
                    correctSound.Play();
                    this.correctNotes++;
                    inputNote ="NONE.";
                    this.waitTime = resetWait;
                    this.generarNota();

                }
                else if(inputNote!= "NONE." && inputNote != this.currentNote){
                    //Si la nota es incorrecta, agregamos uno a las incorrectas y generamos una nueva nota
                    //audio.clip = this.incorrectSound;
                    //audio.Play();
                    incorrectSound.Play();
                    this.incorrectNotes++;
                    inputNote ="NONE.";
                    this.generarNota();
                    this.waitTime = resetWait;
                }
                //Generamos nueva nota

                //Reiniciamos 

            }
            else{
                //Reiniciamos el tiempo 
                this.waitTime = this.resetWait;
                if(!this.firstNote){
                    // Como no presiono nada, nota erronea
                    this.incorrectNotes++;
                    incorrectSound.Play();
                    //audio.clip = this.incorrectSound;
                    //audio.Play();

                    //this.aSource.PlayOneShot(this.incorrectSound);



                }
                else{
                    this.firstNote = false;

                }
                //generamos una nueva nota
                this.generarNota();


            }


        }


    }

    public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb){
        if (blackNotes&&!notePressed) {

        switch (vb.VirtualButtonName) {
            case "buttonC":
                    this.inputNote = "C";
                    //audio.PlayOneShot (c);
                    break;
            case "buttonCSharp":
                    this.inputNote = "C#";
                    //audio.PlayOneShot (cSharp);
                    break;          
            case "buttonD":
                    this.inputNote = "D";
                    //audio.PlayOneShot (d);
                    break;

            case "buttonDSharp":
                    this.inputNote = "D#";
                    //audio.PlayOneShot (dSharp);
                    break;

            case "buttonE":
                    this.inputNote = "E";
                    //audio.PlayOneShot (e);
                    break;
            case "buttonF":
                    this.inputNote = "F";
                    //audio.PlayOneShot (f);
                    break;
            case "buttonFSharp":
                    this.inputNote = "F#";
                    //audio.PlayOneShot (fSharp);
                    break;
            case "buttonG":
                    this.inputNote = "G";
                    //audio.PlayOneShot (g);

                    break;
            case "buttonGSharp":
                    this.inputNote = "G#";
                    //audio.PlayOneShot (gSharp);
                    break;
            case "buttonA":
                    this.inputNote = "A";
                    //audio.PlayOneShot (a);
                    break;
            case "buttonASharp":
                    this.inputNote = "A#";
                    //audio.PlayOneShot (aSharp);
                    break;

            case "buttonB":
                    this.inputNote = "B";
                    //audio.PlayOneShot (b);
                    break;
            case "buttonC2":
                    this.inputNote = "C";
                    //audio.PlayOneShot (c2);
                    break;
            }
            notePressed=true;
                } 
        else if(blackNotes==false && notePressed==false){

            switch (vb.VirtualButtonName) {
            case "buttonC":
                this.inputNote = "C";
                Debug.Log ("Se Presiono C");
                c.Play();
                break;      
            case "buttonD":
                this.inputNote = "D";
                d.Play();
                Debug.Log ("Se Presiono D");
                break;

            case "buttonE":
                this.inputNote = "E";
                e.Play();
                Debug.Log ("Se Presiono E");
                break;
            case "buttonF":
                this.inputNote = "F";
                f.Play();
                Debug.Log ("Se Presiono F");
                break;
            case "buttonG":
                this.inputNote = "G";
                g.Play();
                Debug.Log ("Se Presiono G");
                break;
            case "buttonA":
                this.inputNote = "A";
                a.Play();
                Debug.Log ("Se Presiono A");
                break;

            case "buttonB":
                this.inputNote = "B";
                b.Play();
                           Debug.Log ("Se Presiono B");
                break;
            case "buttonC2":
                this.inputNote = "C";
                c2.Play();
                Debug.Log ("Se Presiono C2");
                break;
            }

            notePressed=true;
        }
    }
        //If para cada tecla del piano

        //audio.PlayOneShot(myClip);

        //Comparamos si las notas son iguales.
        //Si son iguales, sonido correcto+generar una nueva nota+sumar contador de puntos


        //Si no son iguales--> sonido de error+ terminar juego




    public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb){
        notePressed = false;
        this.inputNote = "NONE.";
        Debug.Log ("BUTTON UNPRESSED");



    }
}
```

Here´s also my editor screenshot so you can check that I have audioclips attached to each audio source.
[image]

Can anyone help me  find where the problem is ?

Comment: Are the audio clips 2D or 3D sounds? If they're 3D, is the camera close enough to the audio source to hear them?
EDIT: It also looks like you have another audio source for each sound clip attached to your object? It is better practice to use only one Audio Source component on an object and change the sound clip.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried with one audio source but when I change the clip usually the other sound is still playing and it cuts off the current sound. That's why I tried with multiple audio sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an array, instead of multiple AudioSource. 2 Major problem about the structure of your code.

1 - Only Applies if you use mobile device that can use multiple taps. You're not using Touches

2 - Since you're not using Array. You always, have to remove the current playing Audio Source with a new one instead of iterating from an AudioSource Array. audio.clip will always remove the current one that is playing.

```
AudioSource[] myNotes;
myNotes[0].PlayOnce();
myNotes[3].PlayOnce();

//Don't do this. 
// audio.clip = <---- NO!!!
```